# Which claims are returned from /connect/userinfo?

Tags: identityserver4

Documentation for the userinfo endpoint states:

> Depending on the granted scopes, the UserInfo endpoint will return the
> mapped claims (at least the openid scope is required).

Which claims are "mapped"?  We have a claim in the AspNetUserClaims table that is not being returned.

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html

Comment: If you would like to see what the identity server looks at when you call the userinfo endpoint you can add ```IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;``` to your ConfigureServices in your Startup.cs and then call the userinfo endpoint making sure your have a Bearer token. The server logs will then show what info your token contained.

Comment: @Nicholas_Jones why not just decode the token at https://jwt.io/ ?

Comment: The logs give about the same information but, might also show potential errors and maybe give some insight into your issue. It's just a troubleshooting suggestion not an answer Additionally, if you repeat the test scenario where you claim is not being returned you'll be able to see any logs the identityserver generated about the userinfo.